# Limit deployment rights to Azure from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I want to lock down access to the kudu tools e.g. https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole to a set of ip addresses that azure devops uses. 
I have gone into AzureDevops -> Organisation settings -> Overview and see that my organisation's Azure Devops is held in e.g. West Europe
I have downloaded the list of ip addresses of azure data centers from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=41653

I have gone onto App Service -> Networking blade -> Configure Access restrictions and uploaded the list of ip addresses of e.g. West Europe for .scm.azurewebsites.net.

My understanding is that AzureDevops agents operate from the region specified in organisation settings so if I put in those IP addresses they should be able to acccess the kudu tools fine but instead I get the following error:

```
Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error Code: ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC
More Information: Could not connect to the remote computer ("<myappservice>.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.
Error: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

If I remove the ip addresses it deploys with no problems. How do I limit deployment access to Azure Devops

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't you use Azure RBAC and groups to limit rights?

Answer (score 0):

as the comment by Daniel Mann suggests - you should use Azure RBAC to limit what Azure Devops service principal can do in Azure. If you only allow it to manage specific App Service - it will be able to do only that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal

Comment: It is and does however Azure Security report https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Security/SecurityMenuBlade/0 is saying I need to lock down to source ip addresses and this is what I have been asked to do

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this by simply having a pre-deploy step which disables the ip address restrictions for deployments to .scm.azurewebsites.net and then immediately enables them afterwards. Predeploy step:

```
Write-Host ("Removing IP Address restrictions from scm site")
$apiVersion = ((Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq sites).apiVersions[0]
$webAppConfig = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $webSiteName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -apiVersion $apiVersion)
$webAppConfig.Properties.scmIpSecurityRestrictions = @()
Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $webAppConfig.ResourceId -Properties $webAppConfig.Properties -apiVersion $apiVersion -Force
Write-Host ("Removed IP Address restrictions from scm site")
```

PostDeploy step:
    Write-Host ("Cloudflare firewall enabled - Starting IP Address restrictions")

```
function AddRules($rulesToAdd) {
    $rules = @()
    foreach ($ruleToAdd in $rulesToAdd) 
    {
        $rule = [PSCustomObject] @{
            ipAddress = $ruleToAdd.ipAddress; 
            action = $ruleToAdd.action; 
            priority = $ruleToAdd.priority; 
            name = $ruleToAdd.name; 
            description = $ruleToAdd.description 
            }
        $rules += $rule
    }
return $rules
}

# Access to the main site should only be allowed through cloudflare
[PSCustomObject] $websiteRulesToAdd = 
    @{ipAddress="173.245.48.0/20";action="Allow";priority="100";name="CF01";description="CloudFlare Ip Address"},`
# etc

# Access to the development site should be locked down to developers (NB: These rules are temporarily disabled on deployment)
[PSCustomObject] $scmRulesToAdd = 
    @{ipAddress="X.X.X.X/32";action="Allow";priority="100";name="developer1";description="Developer IP Address"}
# etc

$apiVersion = ((Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq sites).apiVersions[0]
$webAppConfig = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $webSiteName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -apiVersion $apiVersion)
Write-Host ("Writing IP Address restrictions")
$webAppConfig.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions = AddRules -rulesToAdd $websiteRulesToAdd
$webAppConfig.Properties.scmIpSecurityRestrictions = AddRules -rulesToAdd $scmRulesToAdd
Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $webAppConfig.ResourceId -Properties $webAppConfig.Properties -apiVersion $apiVersion -Force
Write-Host ("Completed IP Address restrictions")
```

This is run by AzureDevops as part of the deployment so access is controlled. I hope this is useful to someone

Comment: Are you still using the pre-deploy step to get around this or have you found another way?

Comment: Still using predeploy

Comment: @johnstaveley, are you still doing this?

Comment: I haven't looked into recently if Azure Devops is now a fixed list of IP addresses or not, this would remove the need of this approach